# How to create a plan programmatically?

Tags: braintree

Is there a way to create plans programmatically? It's a bit strange to read

> To create a subscription, you only need a stored paymentMethodToken and a planId, *which must be created via the Control Panel*.

in the [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/java). Why wouldn't there be a way to create a payment plan using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Currently there is no way to create a [Plan](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans) programmatically.

> Plans cannot be created, updated, or deleted via the API

Plans serve as templates for [Subscriptions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/ruby), which can be created through the [Braintree API](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/ruby).

Comment: Thanks! Already contacted support - it seems there's talk going on that it *might* be possible at some point but they didn't make any promises. Seeing that one can overwrite the `price` of a `Plan` adds quite a lot of flexibility though :)